# What does multiple ampersands mean?

Tags: mdx

`[Dim Sportsbook].[Sportsbook].[Sub Product Group].&[4]&[Sportsbook]&[1]`

I know ampersand refers to a member by key, but in the above code, 3 key references are put together.

What does it mean? Are `4`, `Sportsbook`, and `1` all member keys?
And what does it mean when they are put together? 3 different members of the `Sub Product Group`?
Or is it like, `4` is a member of `Sub Product Group`, and then `Sportsbook` is a member of `4` and so on?

Answer (score 0):

it is as you have stated here:

> ... 4 is a member of Sub Product Group, and then Sportsbook is a
> member of 4 and so on

Comment: ok, but why doesn't it have a dot? like &[4].&[Sportsbook]?